# Where do I find drivers for elementary OS?

Tags: system, drivers

If I install elementary OS, where should I get [wifi](/questions/tagged/wifi) [sound](/questions/tagged/sound) and other drivers for my laptop to make these work? I want to delete Windows 10 completely.

Comment: Generally those drivers will already be available in the Linux Kernel. Is impossible to answer you without knowing your laptop brand/model

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to say without knowing what your laptop is. You could look up how compatible your laptop is with ubuntu 18.04, or install elementary on a flash drive and boot your laptop from it to see if everything works.